# How do i remove "random.math" enemies on my canvas at level three

Tags: javascript, createjs

I am creating a small game atm. There is infinite levels in the game. In the different levels enemies spawn from the y-akses with the "Random.math", so they just spawn randomly. There is player, who have to shoot the small enemies.

Regarding to my question. At level 3 i want the "Random.math" enemies to disappear and add a "Boss" istead. A link to the under progress

game

http://www.beproductive.dk/examgame/ss.html

This is my nextLevel function:

```
function nextLevel() {
"use strict"
settings.level++;
addEnemies();
// change text
levelText.text = "level " + settings.level;
// put it to the left of the screen
levelText.x = -100;
levelText.y = -100;
levelText.textAlign = "center";
levelText.textBaseline = "middle";

// animate in
createjs.Tween.get(levelText).to({
        x: 300,
        y: 400

    }, 1500, createjs.Ease.backOut).wait(500).to({
            x: 800,
            y: -100
        },
        1000)
    // animate out

// sound
createjs.Sound.play('vundet');

if (settings.level == 3) {
     console.log("bosslevel");

    var temp = new createjs.Sprite(enemiesSS, "sprite4");
    temp.width = 16;
    temp.height = 16;
    temp.x = 50;
    temp.y = 50;

    stage.addChild(temp);

}
```

}

With this piece of code here, it should remove the ramdom spawn enemies, where only the "Boss" is left on the canvas. I just can't figure it out where to place it in my nextlevel function:

```
   for (var i = enemies.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        stage.removeChild(enemies[i]);
    } enemies = []
```

Yours sincerely

Answer (score 0):

You could create an if statement saying if it's a specific level to add a boss instead of adding enemies.

```
If(level == 30 || level == 40)
    addBoss();

 Else
    addEnemies();
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: THIS IS HOW THE CODE LOOKS LIKE NOW. TRIED TO CONSOLE.LOG IT. " WE ARE AT LVL 3" AND BOSS IS ADDED DOESENT GO THROUGH

```
 console.log("go through")
if (settings.level == 3) {
    console.log("we are at lvl 3 ");
    var temp = new createjs.Sprite(enemiesSS, "sprite4");
    temp.width = 16;
    temp.height = 16;
    temp.x = 50;
    temp.y = 50;
    stage.addChild(temp);
    console.log("boss is added");


} else {
    console.log("enemies added to other lvls");
    addEnemies();
}
```